# Search Multiple Strings for Character Frequencies in R

Tags: r

I recently came across a data set of 10 million passwords and decided it would be interesting to manipulate it in R to see what information the data set holds. This is only my second time using R, but I managed to successfully code a few things, such as the frequency of the first character, the longest and mean password in the data set, the standard deviation, and create a flew frequency plots.

Where I am having trouble now is trying to determine the frequency of specific characters. For example, let's say I want to see the frequency table of numbers used so I can see which numbers are used in passwords the most frequently (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0). I tried using the "grep" function, but that only returned the index. I've also considered turning every password into specific individual characters and then finding the frequency of all characters, but this seems somewhat inefficient. Ultimately What I am hoping to achieve is determine which individual characters are used the most and least frequent, such as the "%" is the least frequently used symbol out of !,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,) where as "!" is the most frequently used.

Does anyone have any advice? Once I get over this hurdle it seems like the code would be easily to replicate to then find the frequency of symbols used, lower case letters, uppercase letters, etc which I should be able to handle.

So let's say I have the following mock code:

```
testpass<-c("devils2000", "rangers1994", "qwerty", "cat$rule!","mattdamon",
 "12345678", "metrics2000", "fishcakes", "vampire", "Rabits2003")

Zero<-table(grepl("0",testpass))
Zero

Two<-table(grepl("2",testpass))
Two

#how many passwords have numbers total
table(grepl(paste(c(1:9, 0), collapse = "|"), testpass))
False    TRUE
    5      5
```

Zero returns the following implying 3/10 (33.33%) of the passwords contains a zero.

```
FALSE  TRUE 
    7     3
```

Two returns - 4/10 or 40% of all passwords contain a 2

```
FALSE  TRUE 
    6     4
```

What I would ideally like to know is if there is a way to test the frequency of the number 0 on a character basis. For example, in the password "devils2000", the character 0 appears more than once, and while it is used in 33.33% of all passwords, it does not represent 33.33% of all characters used.

If this is not possible I am okay with settling with the percent of total passwords reflected above and am curious if there is a way to search multiple characters at once, such as "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9," to find out what percentage of passwords contain any of those numbers. The reason I ask this is because the variable Zero and Two both contain TRUE and FALSE information and I would eventually like to isolate the TRUE numbers and then plot them. Doing this one by one for each character will be tedious and likely not the best approach.

Comment: use `grep("3",Y,value=TRUE)` to return the value instead of the index. That being said your example is not reproducible.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at the code. I believe the code you provided will return all passwords with a specific character rather than determining the frequency of specific characters relative to the entire data set. For example, if I have a single password of "fishfish1%" I would like to know the that "f" appears twice, "i" appears twice, "s" appears twice, "h" appears twice, but "1" and "%" only appear once.
I

Comment: A simple solution is to use: `data.frame(table(strsplit("fishfish1%","")))`

Comment: `grepl` will give you a TRUE/FALSE vector for matches that you can tabulate: `table(grepl("3",Y))`

Comment: Thanks Frank, that is helpful as it does return how many passwords have a specific character or not. However, I am still looking for a solution that gives me frequency of multiple characters relative to all the characters used used in the various password strings. Your solution is certainly a step, but it over looks the fact that a password of "11111111" uses the character "1" eight times and instead returns TRUE once. Still informative regardless, though, so thank you.

Comment: @Metrics, `data.frame(table(strsplit("fishfish1%","")))` does produce the results desired for that single password. Any ideas on how to apply it to the 10 million passwords stored in `samplepass` and test for the frequency of let's say, numbers?

When I try `data.frame(table(strsplit("!@#$%^&*()",samplepass, fixed = TRUE)))` it simply returns 
`Var1 Freq
1 !@#$%^&*()    1`

Comment: Please provide reproducible example (at least 10 passwords (may be hypothetical)) with the expected output if you really want help.

Comment: @Metrics I have updated my original post to reflect your request. I apologize for the ambiguity.

Comment: `grepl(paste(c(1:9, 0), collapse = "|"), testpass)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it in one shot via `strsplit` on a million passwords.  Here I've made the problem reproducible with the begin generation of pws:

```
pass_gen <- function(){
    chars <- c(0:9, LETTERS, letters, c("?", "#", "$", "!", "@"))
    paste(sample(chars, sample(6:10, 1)), collapse="")
}

n <- 1000000
pws <- sapply(1:n, function(i) pass_gen())
```

**## Now strsplit.  If you want percents then divide by the sum of tabe:**

```
chars <- table(unlist(strsplit(paste(pws, collapse=""), NULL)))

chars
100*round(chars/sum(chars), 4)
```